# Html Agility Pack: Find Comment Node

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack, web-scraping

I am scraping a website that uses Javascript to dynamically populate the content of a website with the Html Agility pack.

Basically, I was searching for the XPATH `"\\div[@class='PricingInfo']"`, but that div node was being written to the DOM via Javascript.

So, when I load the page through the Html Agility pack the XPATH mentioned above cannot be found.

It turns out there is a comment before a particular script block I want to parse.

```
<!--Module 328 Buying Options Table-->
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    var data = {
        price: 30.00
    }
</script>
```

For this site, there are many script blocks and so I would need to narrow it down by the finding this auto-generated comment `<!--Module 328 Buying Options Table-->` and the sibling of that node would be the correct script block.

Any idea on how I can search for a particular comment and then just get the adjacent script block?

Thank you!

Comment: +1 for not using regular expressions!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//comment()[contains(., 'Buying Options')]/following-sibling::script")
```

Comment: worked like a charm. thank you! Now, I need a way to parse out the Javascript object.

Comment: Just to add one more thing. Once I got the script note, I was able to parse out the information I needed by using regular expressions. thanks!