# How to access comment section of a page source using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

How can we access the content after `class="hidden_elem"` using selenium, as it does not get loaded into the page source while accessing it. The content in the comments is actually what we need to extract as they are a part of the script that gets run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium webdriver find string from a comment (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971333/selenium-webdriver-find-string-from-a-comment-c)

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: what do you do manually to check the content.